# Angular 4 firebase// function not found in callback

Tags: angular, firebase

Hope you can help me. I am trying to get a callback from firebase. Here is my code

```
createAccount() {

        this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)

            .then(function (message) {
                console.log(message);
                this.setUserProfile();
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            });


}
setUserProfile() {
    // some stuff
}`
```

I try to call `this.setUserProfile()` in callback. The problem is when I set `this.setUserProfile()` in the callback they don't find this function anymore console.log works without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

using `arrow function` to keep the context.

```
this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)

        .then((message) => {      //  <---- use error function here
            console.log(message);
            this.setUserProfile();
        })
        .catch(function (e) {     //  <---- if you use "this" in error callback, change it to arrow function too
            console.log(e);
        });
```